# In Mapfish Print Modules YAML, how do I break a string over multiple lines?

Tags: printing, geoserver, mapfish

In MapFish Printing Module YAML, I have a string that's very long. so I'd like to break the string . What's the syntax for this?

In other words, I have this:

> - !columns
>           config:
>             width: 5
>            # borderWidth: 1
>            # borderColor: black
>             cells:
>               - padding: 10
>                 paddingBottom: 10
>                 vertAlign: middle
>                 width: 5
>                 maxSize: 100
>           absoluteX: 35
>           absoluteY: 111
>           width: 5
>           height:350
>           items:
>             - !text
>               font: Kalpurush
>               fontEncoding: Identity-H
>               fontSize: 12
>               #align: center
>               text: '${onm} ${fnm}'
>               textMaxWidth: 8
>               maxWidth: 5
>               maxHeight: 15

I have parameter as '${Name} ${FatherName}' , I need to put break or newline in String for this parameter.